# Once Einstein, Newton and Archimedes want to play cricket.

Tags: probability

Once Einstein, Newton and Archimedes want to play cricket. All of them will play 6 balls each. Einstein said, I will play at least three shots. Then Newton said, if Einstein becomes true to his words, I will play at least four shots. Archimedes said,I will play at least 5 shots. The probability of playing shots for each ball is 1/2 for everyone. Assume that the probability of being truth of the words of Einstein, Newton and Archimedes are a, b and c respectively.Find a, b , c;

**My work :** 
$a = \frac{3}{12} , b = \frac{3}{12} \cdot \frac{4}{12} , c = \frac{5}{12}  $ 
is the answer ok;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at Einstein. His play is independent of the other's. So his claim is true if the number of his shots is exactly 3, 4, 5 or 6. Find the probability for each of those numbers (they are binomially distributed) and add them up. That yields $a=\frac{21}{32}$. Now Newton's claim is a bit tricky. He says, **if** Einstein is correct. That implies, his claim is correct if Einstein is wrong. So when Einstein has only one shot then Newton is correct whatever the number of his shots. If Einstein is correct then he must have 4, 5 or 6 shots. Add those distinct probabilities up and multiply them by $a$. Add $1-a$ to that result. I get $b=0.5693359$. Archimedes is quite easy again. You should try for yourself.

Comment: 'He says,   why we add $1-a $ to newtons, why it is not$ probability of \quad  (4,5,6) * a$

Comment: Because that is the probability that Einstein is wrong (and therefore Newton is right).

Comment: Then Newton said, if Einstein becomes true to his words, I will play at least four shots. but we should look for when eineistein is true means if he is able to play at least three shots then newton will play at least four shots and  we want the probability of playing at least 4 shots of newton

Comment: how did get  $a= \frac{21}{32}$

Comment: There are two mutually exclusive cases: 1) Einstein is wrong. Then Newton's claim is right. Doesn't matter how many shots he has. The probability for that is $1-a$. 2) Einstein is right (probability $a$). Now Newton must make at least 4 shots (probability $b'$). His play is independent of Einsteins. Therefore you have to multiply the probabilities. So for Newton to be correct you must add the probabilities for the two cases: $b=(1-a)+a\cdot b'$

Comment: How to get $a$? Look at the description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: didn't understand , explain mw here in short how to get a

Comment: The probability of exactly $k$ shots in $n$ plays is $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ with $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Use $n=6$ and calculate the probabilites for $k=3,\ldots ,6$. Add those probabilities to get $a$.